# Cannot get JSON of particular field using NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, mongodb

I am making get request to API endpoint using NodeJS and mongodb.
In app.js:

```
app.get('/api/matches', (req, res) =>{

    //console.log('Get matches..');
    matches.find({}).then(eachOne => {

        res.json(eachOne);

    });

});
```

Above code gives JSON response see below:

[image]

Now I want to get JSON response of a particular match using `app.get()` method but whenever I use below code it always returns JSON data of `id:1` for different URL's like `http://localhost:5000/api/matches/3` or `http://localhost:5000/api/matches/6`

```
app.get('/api/matches/:match_id', (req, res) =>{

    let match = req.params.id;

    matches.findOne({match_id: match}).then(m =>{

        res.json(m);
    });

});
```

Above two URL'S give same JSON data but they should give different JSON data.

```
{
  "_id": "5a63051735aaddd30d1d89cc",
  "id": 1,
  "season": 2008,
  "city": "Bangalore",
  "team1": "Kolkata Knight Riders",
  "team2": "Royal Challengers Bangalore",
  "toss_winner": "Royal Challengers Bangalore",
  "toss_decision": "field",
  "result": "normal",
  "dl_applied": 0,
  "winner": "Kolkata Knight Riders",
  "win_by_runs": 140,
  "win_by_wickets": 0,
  "player_of_match": "BB McCullum",
  "venue": "M Chinnaswamy Stadium",
  "umpire1": "Asad Rauf",
  "umpire2": "RE Koertzen",
  "umpire3": ""
}
```

In matches.js <---Model

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

let Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const matchSchema = new Schema({

    match_id:{
        type:Number,
        required:true
    },

    season:{
        type:Number,
        required:true
    },

    city:{
        type:String,
        required:true
    },

    date:{
        type:Number
    },

    team1:{
        type:String,
        required:true
    },

    team2:{
        type:String,
        required:true
    },


    toss_winner:{
        type:String,
        required:true
    },

    toss_decision:{
        type:String,
        required:true
    },

    dl_applied:{
        type:Number
    },

    winner:{
        type:String,
        required:true
    },

    win_by_runs:{
        type:Number,
        required:true
    },

    win_by_wickets:{
        type:Number,
        required:true
    },

    player_of_match:{
        type:String,
        required:true
    },

    venue:{
        type:String,
        required:true
    },

    umpire1:{
        type:String,
        required:true
    },

    umpire2:{
        type:String,
        required:true
    },

    umpire3:{
        type:String
    }

});

const matches = mongoose.model('matches', matchSchema);

module.exports = matches;
```

Comment: check whether you are passing user_defined or mongoDb generated in the GET request.

Comment: I have edited my question please see matches.js file

Comment: do you have many documents with the same id?

Comment: @Saravana No id is unique id=1,2,3,4,5,...577

Comment: your schema has match_id but the document doesn't have match_id field

Comment: @Saravana is it mandatory to have same field names of schema and document.

Comment: can you set `mongoose.set('debug', true);`  in js and see the query fired for both cases?

Comment: @Saravana I have answered my question please check it out.

Comment: @Saravana Can you please help me out here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48366646/how-to-get-multiple-json-objects-using-nodejs-and-mongoose

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this... gives only two fields city and team1

```
app.get('/api/matches', (req, res) =>{

        //console.log('Get matches..');
        matches.find({},{ city: 1, team1: 1 }).then(eachOne => {

            res.json(eachOne);

        });

    });
```

Answer (score 1):

I have finally fixed the problem here is the code:
In schema field name for `id` was `match_id`.
Field in schema `match_id` is same as `id` in document. You also need to use `parseInt(match)` as URL is string and needs to be converted in to type:Number

```
app.get('/api/matches/:match_id', (req, res) =>{
    let match = req.params.match_id;
    matches.findOne({id: parseInt(match)}).then(m =>{
        res.json(m);
    });
});
```

Comment: @t.niese Should I add some explanation ?

Comment: @t.niese I have added explanation please check if you like it please upvote :)

Answer (score 0):

Your `findOne` should be

```
matches.findOne({ id : match }).then(m =>{ ... } //match id to be matched
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have issue when query with 'match_id' instead of '_id', i don't see it in your collection.